# Binding timespan in wpf mvvm, and show only minutes:seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, timespan

I want to be able to show minutes and seconds in a textbox. The `TextBox` is bound towards a property, which is a `TimeSpan`. In the textbox, the default is : "00:00:00".

This works fine, but how to show only 00:00 where the hours portion is removed.

How do I do this?

This is my binding:

```
public TimeSpan MaxTime
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Examination.MaxTime == 0)
            return TimeSpan.Zero;
        else
            return maxTime;
    }
    set
    {
        maxTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MaxTime");
        TimeSpan x;
        this.Examination.MaxTime = int.Parse(maxTime.TotalSeconds.ToString());                              
    }
}
```

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MaxTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just wanted one way binding, then you could use `StringFormat`:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm':'ss}}" />
```

If you want bidirectional binding, then I would go for a custom value converter.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(String))]
public class HoursMinutesTimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO something like:
        return ((TimeSpan)value).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO something like:
        return TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, "hh':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Escaping the colon in the format string didn't work for me. I had to change it to `{0:hh':'mm}`, that is: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm}}" />`

Comment: or StringFormat={}{0:hh\:mm}

Comment: Just how does this only show minutes and seconds? I understand `hh` to be hour, and `mm` to be minute.

Comment: @ProfK then use `"mm:ss"` or whatever format you need.

Comment: I had the same problem as @sthlm58. Is it worth adding that into this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I took a different tact and created a string called `TimeElapsed` and during a timer tick, I would look at another property which was a `StopWatch` (set during the timer) and then if changed set the string time for showing on the screen.

```
private Stopwatch StopWatch { get; set; }
private double TimeElapsedDouble { get; set; }

private string _TimeElapsed;

public string TimeElapsed
{
    get { return _TimeElapsed; }
    set { _TimeElapsed = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TimeElapsed)); }
}
private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timeElapsedDuration = StopWatch.Elapsed.Duration(); // Get the timespan.

    if (TimeElapsedDouble != timeElapsedDuration.TotalSeconds) // A change happened?
    {
        TimeElapsedDouble = timeElapsedDuration.TotalSeconds;
        TimeElapsed = timeElapsedDuration.ToString(@"mm\:ss"); // Answer is here
    }

}
```

Then just bind it to the control as needed

```
<Label Content="{Binding TimeElapsed}" />
```