# WPF TimeSpan binding to label without milliseconds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my current project i'm trying to show a label which has a TimeSpan binding.
Actually the xaml looks simple:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataSource.TimeTotal, StringFormat={}{0:hh\:mm}}"/>
```

Which is exactly what is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974763/binding-timespan-in-wpf-mvvm-and-show-only-minutesseconds). But it doesn't work, it shows always the full time and not only hours + minutes.

I tested a lot of solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? TimeSpan only gained format strings in .NET 4.

Comment: @Asif Tested it already, doesn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet .NET 4.0, non-client profile. That's the point its not working and it makes me angry right now. :-/

Comment: Maybe just try to use `TextBox` instead of a `Label` and bind `Text` instead of `Content`. You can find example of the binding here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563081/how-to-format-timespan-in-xaml. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Lucas Actually this is working, but i'm wondering why it's not supported by .NET so i gonna leave this question open for other readers.

Comment: It works with TextBlock, which is the lightweight equivalent to Label.  Whenever you're binding to a dependency property in a control that uses a `ContentPresenter` to display the data, it seems to eat the `StringFormat` you've provided. (in `Label`, `Button`, etc).  Wish someone would let us know why!  You can nest a `TextBlock` within the `Label` or just go with a `TextBlock` (which, unless you need access text, is usually a better choice anyway).

Comment: Since it worked, I'll post it as an answer. I'll also add some more information that I've just found :).

Comment: @Felix: I meant posting my comment with using `TextBlock` instead of `Label` and extending it with some alternative solutions and other information I've found.

Comment: @FelixK. Sure, here it is [as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10591149/24399).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suggested solution**

Maybe just try to use `TextBox` instead of a `Label` and bind `Text` instead of `Content`. You can find example of the binding here: [How to format TimeSpan in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563081/how-to-format-timespan-in-xaml). It's also worth noticing that `TextBlock` is more lightweight then `Label`, so it should be used when possible.

**Alternative solutions**

If you want to use `Label` for some reason, there seems to be [a property called `ContentStringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) of a `Label` itself, so your xaml can look like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataSource.TimeTotal}" ContentStringFormat="hh\\:mm"/>
```

Another solution would be implementing a custom `IValueConverter`, where you can pass string format as converter's parameter and format the value manually in the converter's code. This solution should then work correctly for all appropriate control types. More about value converters can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx).

**String formatting properties**

As ***Erode*** wrote in the comment, there seem to be other controls for which `StringFormat` does not work. 
However, for controls derived from `ContentControl` you should be able to use `ContentStringFormat` and for controls derived from `ItemsControl`, there is a `ItemStringFormat` property. There is a link with few samples presenting how to use those:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It works with `TextBlock`, which is the lightweight equivalent to `Label`. Whenever you're binding to a dependency property in a control that uses a `ContentPresenter` to display the data, it seems to eat the `StringFormat` you've provided. (in `Label`, `Button`, etc). Wish someone would let us know why! You can nest a `TextBlock` within the Label or just go with a `TextBlock` (which, unless you need access text, is usually a better choice anyway).